# Ignore case smarty replace bold?

Tags: php, replace, smarty, explode, bold

I have a form where the user enters a keyword or a group of keywords.

Let's say he types in, "beautiful flowers".

The database returns some results:
1.Flowers are beautiful.
2.The red rose and daisy are beautiful flowers.

PHP:

```
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];

// splits keywords.
$ExplodeKeywords = explode(" ", $keyword);
// assign keyword(s) to be bolded.
$tpl->assign('ExplodeKeywords', $ExplodeKeywords);
```

Template file:

```
{$row.Text|replace:"`$ExplodeKeywords[0]`":"<b>`$ExplodeKeywords[0]`</b>"}
```

However it is only bolding the exact words that were typed in the search like this:

1.Flowers are **beautiful**.
2.The red rose and daisy are **beautiful** **flowers**.

But I want it to bold any word that was entered regardless of case (like this).

1.**Flowers** are **beautiful**.
2.The red rose and daisy are **beautiful** **flowers**.

I'm confused on what I have to do to make this work and if I should program it from the PHP or the template file.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to do in php:

```
$text_formated = preg_replace('/(' . implode('|',$ExplodeKeywords) . ')/gi', '<b>$1</b>', $text_orig);
```

Comment: I don't understand how that solves the, "Case sensitivity" issue.

This only highlights the word the user searches for. If the user types in "and". It will not highlight "And" only the lowercase "and".

Comment: you are right. I missed that part at first. I modified the answer. The i preg_replace modifier should help.

Comment: How would I use this if my data is coming from a MYSQL database?

Comment: Set the variable with the data coming from mysql, and when the variables are ready call this function.